# What is the correct way to specify a null column with sequelize-typescript?

Tags: typescript, null, sequelize.js

I cannot see any documentation on how to specify the javascript type of NULL columns in `sequelize-typescript`.

For example (the default `@Column` is `allowNULL=true`):

```
@Column
my_property?: string | null
my_other_property: string | null
```

both results in the following error `Specified type of property 'my_property' cannot be automatically resolved to a sequelize data type`.

Am I doing something wrong, or is the correct way merely:

```
@Column
my_property?: string
```

In which case, what does the ORM return when the database value is NULL? Does `my_property` become `null` or `undefined`?

Any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The first way is correct with regards to `null` and works for some columns as of sequelize-typescript@2.1.3. The error is because you did not specify the column data type, and there are multiple column types that could correspond to a JS `string` type and the fallback code is not able to pick one. I recommend always specifying the column's data type to make this clear:

```
@Column({ type: DataType.STRING })
my_property?: string | null
```